# I get unexpected response after sending ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, response, send

first of all , I send data to check_address.php page which its code is :

```
$x=1;
echo $x;
```

and the ajax request code is :

```
jQuery.ajax({
         url:'../admin/parsers/check_address.php',
         method:'post',

         success:function(resp){

                 if(resp != 1){
                    alert(resp);
           }
           if(resp == 1){
                alert('hello');
           }

         },
         error:function(){alert('something wrong');},

     });
```

The response which is unexpected is shown in this image :
[image]

but i expect to alert hello message...so where is the wronge in this code and thanks in advance

Comment: check_address.php did you share all the codes?

Comment: Looks like xdebug is on, turn it off maybe?

Comment: Özgür Can Karagöz .....yes check_address.php has only these two lines of code

Comment: Musa ...I did not understand what you have said ..please clarify your answer

Answer (score -1):

**First of all** *I think* js can't expect numbers from php like this .. it expect string .. your code should be something like

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url:'../admin/parsers/check_address.php',
     method:'post',
     success:function(resp){
               var resp = resp.trim();  // use trim to avoid white spaces
               alert(resp);
               /*if(resp !== '1'){
                   alert(resp);
               }
               if(resp == '1'){
                  alert('hello');
               }*/
     },
     error:function(){alert('something wrong');},

});
```

**Note:** this code must work if your `url` path is correct .. if you still get the same error .. use the full path .. like `url: 'http://www.website.com/admin/parsers/check_address.php'`

to check if the file work you can directly access `http://www.website.com/admin/parsers/check_address.php` in your browser and it should print 1

Comment: Thank u for your answer but it does not work i still facing the same unexpected alert message

Comment: OK ya @Ibrahim remove the `if`s  and just `alert(resp)` and let me know what you got .. and if your site is live let me check it